Subtlety in proving that the product of two measurable function is measurable
Let $X$ be a measurable space and let $f,g : X \to [-\infty, \infty]$ be measurable functions. I want to show that the product $fg$ is also measurable. I know that we have to use the identity
$$
fg = \frac{1}{2}[(f+g)^2 - f^2 - g^2]
$$
but the problem is that this identity holds only when $f$ and $g$ take real values.
Any help or hints will be highly appreciated.

Why does it not hold when $f$ and $g$ take complex values?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend no, the issue is with $\pm\infty$. We need to take this into account as well. Anyway OP, this has definitely been asked before, I’m sure there’s a dupe somewhere.

Consider the cases when $fg$ takes the values of $\pm\infty$ and discuss them separately.

Note that $0\cdot \infty$ is not defined, so the problem looks ill posed. It would make more sense to consider $f,g:X\rightarrow (0, \infty]$.

Note that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both real then
$$
f(x)g(x) = \frac{1}{2}[(f(x)+g(x))^2 - f(x)^2 - g(x)^2].
$$
Now let
$$
h = \frac{1}{2}[(f+g)^2 - (f^2 + g^2)].
$$
Then $h$ is a measurable function (the bracketing is important as addition is not associative in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$). Let $Y = \{x \in X : f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Observe that for a fixed real $a$ we have
$$
 (fg)^{-1}((a, \infty]) \cap Y = h^{-1}((a, \infty]) \cap Y
$$
Finally we have
\begin{multline*}
(fg)^{-1}((a, \infty]) = [f^{-1}(\infty) \cap g^{-1}(\infty)] \cup [f^{-1}(-\infty) \cap g^{-1}(-\infty)] \\
\cup [f^{-1}(\infty) \cap g^{-1}((0, \infty])] \cup [f^{-1}((0, \infty]) \cap g^{-1}(\infty)] \cup [f^{-1}(-\infty) \cap g^{-1}([-\infty, 0))] \\
\cup [f^{-1}([-\infty, 0)) \cap g^{-1}(-\infty)] \cup [h^{-1}((a, \infty]) \cap Y]
\end{multline*}
if $a \geq 0$. Thus $(fg)^{-1}((a, \infty])$ is measurable as each of the set appearing above is measurable. If however $a < 0$ then we need to add the sets $f^{-1}(\infty) \cap g^{-1}(0)$, $f^{-1}(-\infty) \cap g^{-1}(0)$, $f^{-1}(0) \cap g^{-1}(\infty)$, and $f^{-1}(0) \cap g^{-1}(-\infty)$ as well which are all measurable and so we are done.

What happens if $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=\infty$?

Even if you only consider $f,g:X\rightarrow (0,\infty]$ (to avoid the undefined case $0\cdot \infty$), I do not think the function $(1/2)[(f+g)^2-f^2-g^2]$ is helpful, since it is not defined when $f=\infty$ and $g=1$ (because $\infty - \infty$ is not defined). Instead, the best approach may be to first observe that the product of real-valued measurable functions is measurable, then extend to infinite-valued functions using the Hirofumi comment. Just show the following are in the sigma algebra for $X$: ${fg=\infty}, {fg=-\infty}, {fg\in B}$ for $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

@Michael I have considered the case $f^{-1}(0) \cap g^{-1}(\infty)$.

The issue is bigger than any particular cases that you might consider. The issue is that the function $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ may not even be defined if $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=\infty$. So the problem itself is ill posed. It would make sense to consider functions $f,g:X\rightarrow (0, \infty]$. Or you can state some particular convention for $0\cdot \infty$, perhaps $0\cdot \infty = 0$, but that would need to be clarified as the convention is that $0\cdot \infty$ is not defined. Or you could view this as a function $fg:X\rightarrow [-\infty, \infty] \cup {undefined}$.

Yes, I am using the convention $0 \cdot \infty = 0$. With this convention everything works out just fine.
